# Regex search for characters like "/", "<" and ">"

Tags: regex

What should be the regex pattern if my texts contain the characters like "\ / > <" etc and I want to find them. That's because regex treats "/" like it's part of the search pattern and not an individual character.

For example, I want to find `Super Kings` from the string `<span>Super Kings</span>`, using VB 2010.

Thanks!

Comment: You should not try to use regex to parse xml or html.  Find an html or xml parser to do it for you or you'll drown.

Comment: Could you please advice of an HTML parser that works in both VB 2010 Win32 and Windows Phone 7 applications?

Comment: You are not likely to get a lot of sympathy.   If you read the documentation on your regex matcher, it will tell how how to match characters that are normally used as part of the search pattern, unless you have a truly awful regex engine.

Comment: For future travelers who come across this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/194309

Answer (score 1):

**Just try this:**

```
\bYour_Keyword_to_find\b
```

`\b` is used in RegEx for matching word boundary.

[EDIT]

You might be looking for this:

```
(?<=<span>)([^<>]+?)(?=</span>)
```

**Explanation:**

```
<!--
(?<=<span>)([^<>]+?)(?=</span>)

Options: case insensitive; ^ and $ match at line breaks

Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind) «(?<=<span>)»
   Match the characters “<span>” literally «<span>»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «([^<>]+?)»
   Match a single character NOT present in the list “<>” «[^<>]+?»
      Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «+?»
Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=</span>)»
   Match the characters “</span>” literally «</span>»
-->
```

[/EDIT]

Comment: But the words must exist within the HTML tag specified, and not just some random word from the whole HTML source.

Comment: I think the issue is that the keyword isn't known; asker wants to find whatever is within span tags.

Comment: Then try this: ``(?<=<span>)Your_Keyword_to_find(?=</span>)``

Answer (score 1):

In regex you must escape the `/` with `\`.

For instance, try: <strike>`<span>(.*)<\/span>`</strike> `<span>([^<]*)<\/span>` or `<span>(.*?)<\/span>`

Read more from:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html

Comment: Make sure that quantifier is lazy, not greedy.

Comment: What about further limiting: `<span>([^<]*)<\/span>` This way it will match until it finds another `<`

Comment: @PeterOlson `<span>([^<]*)<\/span>` works, but the tags are included in the search result. Is there a way to remove the tags and only return the actual words?

Comment: If interested in the lazy solution: `<span>(.*?)<\/span>`, for more info read http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: Depending on how VB 2010 handles RegEx, anything within () should be returned as a separate variable, as in a search/replace you would access it with `$1`

Comment: -1, ``<span>(.*)<\/span>`` supposed to fail for searching within ``<span>test1</span> other data <span>test2</span>``.

Comment: Fair point, and that's why the further comments express a `not <` and lazy search method.